# Bootstrap How-to: checkbox should change text input value when selected/checked

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I just started with HTML/CSS/JavaScript and running into a (hopefully) small obstacle while testing Bootstrap.

My code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text1" name="text1" value="Initial Value" readonly>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox col-sm-10">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse3rdParty"
                   aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse3rdParty">
            Select to change value
        </label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="collapse" id="collapse3rdParty">
    <div class="form-group form-group-lowermargin">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" name="inputName" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Live Demo also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shaw2ep6/1/).

What I already managed to achieve is 'collapsing out' an input field when the checkbox is checked.

What I couldn't find was any info on how to make that same checkbox change the value of the read-only text input (or maybe I didn't get it).

By default, i.e. when loading the page, it should have an initial value. When the checkbox gets checked, the value of the text input should get altered (so e.g. changing 'value="Initial Value"' to 'value="New Value"').

Is this possible without having to use JavaScript?

Any help on how to do this (either by CSS or JS) is highly appreciated ;-)

Comment: So do you want the value of the box to change when someone types in the other box?

Comment: Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/shaw2ep6/2/

Comment: @Yvette: I will remember this, thanks for the clarification. Question has been answered by Ryan (I've marked the working solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to change the value of the text input without JavaScript. The following uses the jQuery framework, as opposed to the solution by @Lg102 which uses pure JavaScript.

This will change the input field once:

```
$('#checkbox').on('change', function(){
    if (this.checked) {
        $('#text1').val('New value');
    }
});
```

This will toggle between the initial value and the new value based on whether the checkbox is checked:

```
$('#checkbox').on('change', function(){
    if (this.checked) {
        $('#text1').val('New value');
    } else {
        $('#text1').val('Initial value');
    }
});
```

Comment: Wow, all of you, you are awesome ;-)
I've used the toggle script with the if/else clause which worked like a charm and did exactly what expected - perfect!

Answer (score 1):

It *could* be done in CSS by using the `:checked` selector, combined with `~`, but only if the field is *after* the checkbox in the DOM, so I wouldn't recommend it.

In (plain, no jQuery) JavaScript:

```
var initial = document.getElementById('text1'),
    checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox');

checkbox.addEventListener('change', function(){
    initial.value = this.checked ? 'CHECKED' : 'NOT CHECKED'; 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it worked just the way it should, though I'm using the if/else jQuery version from @Ryan - still, great job!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use javascript. You could do it like this :

```
document.getElementById('checkbox').onchange = function()  {
  document.getElementById('inputName').setAttribute('placeholder', this.checked ? 'new name' : 'name') 
}
```

**https://jsfiddle.net/d0fyxg8e/**

---

jQuery version :

```
$('#checkbox').change(function() {
  $('#inputName').attr('placeholder', this.checked ? 'new name' : 'name') 
})
```

**https://jsfiddle.net/594s2mtf/**